# In a module, using accessors blows up

Tags: ruby

My module:

```
# test.rb
module Database
  # not used in this example, but illustrates how I intend to include the module in class
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :db, :dbname
    self.dbname = ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'test' ? 'mydb_test' : 'mydb'
  end
end
```

When I load it, I get this:

```
test.rb:7:in `<module:ClassMethods>': undefined method `dbname=' for Database::ClassMethods:Module (NoMethodError)
    from bin/test:7:in `<module:Database>'
    from bin/test:1:in `<main>'
```

Can't figure out why. If I check `instance_methods`, it's empty before `attr_accessor`, and has the appropriate four methods after. Yet when I call them, they don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor` defines instance methods on `ClassMethods` (such as `ClassMethods#dbname=`), but you are trying to call a class method (`ClassMethods.dbname=`).

Comment: I see.  I guess I got thrown off because `instance_methods` was showing the method.  Perhaps I should move the usage of the accessors into the `included` block...

Comment: Actually, that won't work.  I do need the accessors to be class-level, because the attribute will be.  (It's for a Sinatra::Base, which doesn't get instantiated till the first call, but the connection should happen at load time.)

Comment: Ok, it worked when I left `attr_accessor` as is, but then used `base.dbname =` inside the `included(base)` block.

Comment: odigity, now that you have it worked out, you may wish to delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

With *self.dbname = ENV...*, you are calling a method *#self.dbname=*, which doesn't exist. Maybe this is what you are after?

```
# test.rb
module Database
  # not used in this example, but illustrates how I intend to include the module in class
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :db, :dbname
    def self.dbname ; ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'test' ? 'mydb_test' : 'mydb' ; end
    puts self.dbname
  end
end
```